# How to sort based on a choice field in django in template

Tags: python, django

Consider the following model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    POSITIONS = (
            ('L', 'Left'),
            ('R', 'Right')
        )
    position = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=POSITIONS, default='R')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to sort the objects in a manner such that I can separate the left ones from the right ones and show them in separate parts of the html document. Something like:

```
{% for category in categories|sort_by: "position" = "left" %}
        <ul class="collection with-header">
         <li class="collection-header">
          <h3>{{category.name}}</h3>
             <p><small>{{category.description}}</small></p>
         </li>
            {% for url in category.extra_link_set.all %}
            <li class="collection-item"><a href="{{url.url}}">{{url.url_text}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}

        </ul>
        {% endfor %}
```

I know this wont work. But I am just trying to give an idea as to what I want. Also would the process be similar for any other field type in django models?

Comment: What you want isn't sorting, it's just separating out the left and the right. You can do that with a simple `if` within your loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <div class="left_stuff">
        {% if category.position=='L' %}
            <h3>...</h3>
            .....
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% for category in categories %}
    <div class="right_stuff">
        {% if category.position=='R' %}
            <h3>...</h3>
            .....
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You could further simplify this by parameterising the if statement and extracting the shared code to a separate template that is included.